# Popup in chrome extension showing different screens

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making chrome extension, that has a popup.html . That look like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popupstyle.css">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="timer">
    Time : 
        <input id="timerInput" type="text" placeholder="in milliseconds">
    </div>
    <div class="flex">
        <input type="button" class="flex-child" id="mystartbutton" value="Start">
        <input type="button" class="flex-child" id="mystopbutton"  value="Stop">
   </div>
</div>
```

The popupstyle.css is something like this :

```
.flex {
display: flex;
width: 50%;
float: right;
height: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 5px;
}
}

.flex-child {
-webkit-box-flex: 1 1 auto;
-moz-box-flex:  1 1 auto;
-webkit-flex:  1 1 auto;
-ms-flex:  1 1 auto;
flex:  1 1 auto;
margin-right:5px;
}
input[type=button] {
width: 30em;  height: 5em;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.wrapper {
width: 500px;
border: 1px solid black;
overflow: hidden;
}
.timer {
width: 225px;
float: left;
height: 20px;
padding: 5px;
}
```

But in some chrome browser it looks fine as expected :

[image]

But in some it looks like this :

[image]

What can be reason behind such unexpected behaviour ?

I want to increase height of both buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is wrong: container is 20px high and the buttons are 5em which is ~3 times higher, so the buttons are clipped and their centered labels are invisible just below the border.

Some browser versions apparently ignore the specified height for buttons which sounds like a bug.

To increase the height of buttons without clipping you should increase the height of the container:

```css
.flex {
    height: 6em;
}
```

To make the buttons fill the entire height:

```css
input[type=button] {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What is correct CSS then according to you ? Also if I am suppose to increase height of my buttons, whats right way to do it ?

Comment: And what about button heights ? When i increase there height it is not being reflected. It is still same. Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/n3btzpe0/

Comment: You're amazing :-) http://jsfiddle.net/wOxxOm/n3btzpe0/2/ and the screenshot https://puu.sh/khLHi/c4c2765874.png

Comment: It is surely browser problem :( #annoyed